# What are the messages I see during the startup/shutdown process of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, shutdown

[image: boot process messages]

[image: shutdown process messages]

When I turn on my PC it is apparently checking all the drives and giving an OK message (in green color), and it does the same when I shut down.

I want to know what those messages are and how they are produced.

Does this indicate any problem with my system and if yes, what commands should I run to correct it?

Comment: **To close voters:** This does not seem unclear to me and the presence of answers indicate the same.

Comment: @Videonauth can you edit it to make it clearer what OP means then? I don't understand it, and the answers all say something different and seem to be guessing what OP wants to know. None of them has been upvoted and I don't feel able to upvote any of them.

Comment: I have edited it myself based on [your interpretation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41517182#41517182) but I am not at all sure this is what was intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **SHORT ANSWER**

**If you are a new user and your system is actually working properly, please do not worry about this. There is no need to do anything and unnecessarily mess up things.**

---

This is a normal boot process during which all the system services and components will start and begin doing their job(or end, during shut down). This process happens in any OS, even windows. All these are collectively just callled-**THE SYSTEM IS BOOTING UP**.

Usually, these are hidden by the OS logo (example:Ubuntu logo with dots) so that boot process looks nice, without these messages. This is only a cosmetic arrangement called as **splash screen** and needs no worry, if the messages are not hidden.

Instead of trying to hide these messages, they can help you learn about what all things happen when your computer boots up. This will help you gain good insights into your computer hardware and OS components, if you have an inquisitive mind to  learn.

So, just don't worry about these messages and leave them as they are.

---

***A quick analogy to this would be:***

A lathe with casing for the drive gears v/s a lathe with gears always visible. With casing, the lathe might look better finished, still the gears will be running the exactly same way if they weren't covered :p Haha!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is the Linux Kernel loading up and making sure that things are starting and stopping without issue.

For in-depth information on the Linux Kernel and boot order see: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/

Answer (score 0):

Every OS mac, windows,Linux etc at boot time loads drivers,file-system and services. What you are seeing is the Linux way of booting. You can take a closer look on what scripts are executed on startup in `/etc/init.d/` which holds scripts executed at boot time.